# Windows updates don't work after fresh installation of windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 but windows update don't work! Windows updates return with an error. Rebooting doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use update catalog to install the first two updates (kind of install updates standalone, offline).

1. go to Microsoft [Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx)
2. Search for **KB3020369** and download it for your flavor of Windows 7 (x84 or x64). I would pick save file to disk.
3. Install it from the saved file.
4. Now do the same for the second update **KB3172605**. Search, download and install.

Reboot the system and run Windows Updates and it should run fine now!

Source: [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-7-update-problems-read-this-first/28147a5f-b0b0-480b-bed9-834a2da7a375) but screenshots there are a bit out of date now. You just have to download each install, instead of adding it to basket.

P.S As an added note, I had also installed IE11 since stock Windows 7 comes with IE8 and it doesn't open all sites due to being out of date. So you might want to install Google Chrome browser, download Internet Explorer 11 and that processes also does some updates to system. This step is probably not needed though.